# Create observable from component method, that is called as an event handler

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a component, that looks like this:

```
@Component({
    template: `
    ...
    <child-component (childEvent)="onChildEvent()"></child-component>
`
})
export class ParentComponent {
    onChildEvent() {
        ...
    }
}
```

I want to turn the calls to the `onChildFinished` method into an observable sequence.

Now, if the method in question was a handler for some "native" DOM event such as click, blur, etc, I would've used `Observable.fromEvent`, but in this case this does not seem to be applicable (as there is no native event involved).

The only thing that comes to mind is something like this:

```
@Component({
    template: `
    ...
    <child-component (childEvent)="onChildEvent()"></child-component>
`
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private childEventStream: Observable<void>;

    // I am not sure, what is the type of this,
    // seems like an internal RxJS thing
    private observer: any; 

    onChildEvent() {
        this.observer.next();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.childFinishedStream = Observable.create(
            observer => this.observer = observer;
        );
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.observer.completed();
    }
}
```

It seems, that there must be a better way, since this has to be quite tedious to maintain if there are multiple handlers involved.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you just want an [**`EventEmitter`**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/EventEmitter-class.html)?

These are created like this:

```
@Component({
    template: `
      <child-component (finished)="onChildFinished($event)"></child-component>
    `
})
export class ParentComponent {

    onChildFinished(data: number) {
        //...
    }
}
```

And the child component using `Output`.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'child-component',
    template : `hi`
})
export class ChildComponent {

    @Output()
    public finished: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();

    private _imFinishing(): void {
        finished.emit(1);
    }
}
```

Perhaps I am not understanding your question right, but this seems to be what you want.

Comment: This is exactly how it's done on the _child_ side (otherwise how would've I been able to listen to child events in the parent controller)

Comment: Ahh, i think i understand it better now. You want to sorta listen for a child event to be finished. This is against the angular2 guide. Data goes down, events go up.. Better would be to use a service, and set an `EventEmitter` there. Let your parent component listen to that, and let whatever your childComponent does handle there as well

Comment: No, sorry, it has nothing to do with "finishing" anything. Perhaps, I've chosen a bad (suggestive) name for the event. I've edited the question to leave out the word "finish". It is just some event, that is emitted by the child controller with no special meaning.

Comment: Perhaps it's because it's early :) but i still don't understand. Looking at your question now I guess you want this: ChildComponent -> ParentComponent -> GrandParentComponent. An event on the ChildComponent is captured by ParentComponent which triggers and event on it's own which can be captured by a GrandParentComponent..

Comment: I am not sure, how you came to this conclusion. I want to turn a sequence of calls of some method of a component into an observable sequence (`Observable` with a capital O).

Thanks very much for trying to help, though.

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot help you :) I do not see why you want to use an `Observable` instead of an `EventEmitter`.